React native snap carousel
I'm working on a react native expo app and I'm getting :   TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined, js engine: Hermes. It's related to the Carousel package
I've tried to you the reanimated carousel but I'm unable to use the pagination

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use Swiper for carousel, it is very easy to use. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swiper
